# Deploy Angular2 Application with angular-cli

Tags: angular, deployment, angular-cli

I'm new in Angular2. I've read a few things about deployment of ng2 apps.

1) I have installed latest beta version of angular-cli.

2) Then I've created a new project with angular-cli.

3) Then I've run ng build command and copied/pasted the content of dist folder on a new folder on my wamp server.

After I try to reach the url on my browser, having my server running I get the following state of the application.

"Loading..." and the app component never loads. No errors or anything ? Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: There's an option to build to github pages, try using that option, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#deploying-the-app-via-github-pages

The default build does not support regularly serving the files. Also, the cli is a work in progress and many features are broken or rewritten regularly. So it might be just a bug. If you can show more of your output I can try looking more into it, or open an issue on the repo.

Comment: I don't do anything special. The procedure I describe is pretty straightforward. I'm just trying to load a blank app which was build with the relevant cli command, produced with angular-cli on my localhost without ng serve. You can try to do it yourself as well.

Comment: I was asking for your output, because when I run it and throw it on my regular server it works. So I want to know what is different on your setup. Maybe is your XAMP not working right? try using the package nws

Comment: It seems like when I build it to github pages the produced dist folder is working properly on server. Thanks ! Is there any more consistent webpack where I can rely on for build future ng2 applications ?

Comment: Not at the moment that I know of. But the core maintainer is Filipe Silva and he's working a lot on it, he usually posts about progress on twitter https://twitter.com/filipematossilv

Better support for dist and being able to work with existing applications, and systems different to webpack are currently in high priority.